# How do I check how much RAM a process consumes like the way `time` is used to measure the elapsed time?

Tags: process, memory, statistics, measure

How do I check the maximum amount a RAM a process uses similar to how `time` works?

```
$ time mvn package
real    0m35.796s
user    0m32.925s
sys     0m1.559s

$ maxmem mvn package
688 MB
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using GNU `time` instead of the built-in.

On CentOS, you would install it with `yum install time` then run it with `/usr/bin/time <command>`

Note that you need to specify the full path; otherwise the shell will want to use the built-in time

Comment: Oh wow I didn't know that was a built-in and `/usr/bin/time` already gives memory usage.